# Xray -Artifactory Integration [ Failed to save access Config]

Tags: jfrog-xray

Today I upgraded my Xray to 2.2.3 and in this version too Xray should use Artifactory as authentication provider. So when I tried to change it in the Xray console, it is throwing the following error as Failed to save Access config.

It will be very helpful if you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue. I tried many things but in the end, restarting the xray-server (container in my case) fixed the issue for me. (Crying out loud).